# Sort an array of dictionaries in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Suppose we have

```
var filesAndProperties:Dictionary<String, Any>[]=[] //we fill the array later
```

When I try sorting the array using

```
filesAndProperties.sort({$0["lastModified"] > $1["lastModified"]})
```

Xcode says "could not find member subscript".

How do I sort an array of such dictionaries by values in a specific key?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The error message is misleading. The real problem is that the Swift compiler does
not know what type of object `$0["lastModified"]` is and how to compare them.

So you have to be a bit more explicit, for example

```
filesAndProperties.sort {
    item1, item2 in
    let date1 = item1["lastModified"] as Double
    let date2 = item2["lastModified"] as Double
    return date1 > date2
}
```

if the timestamps are floating point numbers, or

```
filesAndProperties.sort {
    item1, item2 in
    let date1 = item1["lastModified"] as NSDate
    let date2 = item2["lastModified"] as NSDate
    return date1.compare(date2) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending
}
```

if the timestamps are `NSDate` objects.

Answer (score 2):

Here, The problem is that compiler unable to understand type that what of object **$0["lastModified"]** is.

**if the timestamps are floating point numbers:-**

```
filesAndProperties = filesAndProperties.sorted(by: {
                (($0 as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)["lastModified"] as? Double)! < (($1 as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)["lastModified"] as? Double)!
            })
```